# How to create div with background-image by using for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have about 9 images that i need to set it as a div background-image. And each div got its own position. i need to loop to create div tag with different background-image. how can i do that?

Comment: different back ground image for each div and div will be created dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple enough to build a `style` attribute with a `background-image` property in it.

```
/* JavaScript + jQuery
 * var listOfImageSrcs = [
 *     '/rooted/path/to/file',
 *     'relative/path/to/file',
 *     'https://domain.tld/url/to/file'
 * ];
for(i in listOfImageSrcs) {
    var src = listOfImageSrcs[i];
    $('<div style="background-image: url(\'' + src + '\');"></div>').appendTo('body');
}

/* PHP
 * $listOfImageSrcs = array(
 *     '/rooted/path/to/file',
 *     'relative/path/to/file',
 *     'https://domain.tld/url/to/file'
 * );
 */
<?php foreach($listOfImageSrcs AS $src): ?>
    <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo($src); ?>');"></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You'll also need to make sure the `div`s have `width` and `height` defined (in order for them to be visible).

If you have `background-position` information in that list of images you can add that to the `style` tag as well.

Comment: Why php code? he tagged the question with javascript/jquery..

Comment: Good point. I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

Well with the context you provided its hard to answer but you can use
[$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop the content and then you can use [$().css("background-image", "url(image.jpg)");](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the background image.